# Plot output differences between python and julia

Tags: python-3.x, plot, julia

I am trying to use julai as main language for my work. But I find that this plot is different than python (Which outputs the right plot)
Here is the python code and output

```
import numpy as np 
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
u = 9.27*10**(-21)
k = 1.38*10**(-16)
j2 = 7/2
nrr = 780
h = 1000
na = 6*10**(23)
rho = 7.842
mgd = 157.25
a = mgd
d = na*rho*u/a
m_f = []
igd = 7.0
for t in range(1,401):
    while True: 
        h1 = h+d*nrr*igd
        x2 = (7*u*h1)/(k*t)
        x4 = 2*j2
        q2 = (x4+1)/x4
        m = abs(7*(q2*math.tanh(q2*x2)**-1 - (1/x4)*math.tanh(x2/x4)**-1))
        if abs(m - igd) < 10**(-12):
            break
        else:
            igd = m
    m_f.append(abs(m))
plt.plot(range(1,401), m_f)
plt.savefig("Py_plot.pdf")
```

and it gives the following right plot

[The right plot as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJ8jE.png)

But when I do the same calculations in julia it gives different output than python, here is my julia code

```
using Plots
u = 9.27*10^(-21)
k = 1.38*10^(-16)
j2 = 7/2
nrr = 780
h = 1000
na = 6*10^(23)
rho = 7.842
mgd = 157.25
a = mgd
d = na*rho*u/a
igd = 7.0
m = 0.0
m_f = Float64[]
for t in 1:400
    while true
        h1 = h+d*nrr*igd
        x2 = (7*u*h1)/(k*t)
        x4 = 2*j2
        q2 = (x4+1)/x4
        m = 7*(q2*coth(rad2deg(q2*x2))-(1/x4)*coth(rad2deg(x2/x4)))
        if abs(abs(m)-igd) < 10^(-10)
            break
        else
            igd = m
        end
     end  
    push!(m_f, abs(m))
end
plot(1:400, m_f)
```

and this is the unexpected julia output
[unexpected wrong output from julia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vBUy.png)

I wish for help....

Answer (score 3):

##### Code:

```
using Plots

const u = 9.27e-21
const k = 1.38e-16
const j2 = 7/2
const nrr = 780
const h = 1000
const na = 6.0e23
const rho = 7.842
const mgd = 157.25
const a = mgd
const d = na*rho*u/a

function plot_graph()
  igd = 7.0
  m = 0.0
  trange = 1:400
  m_f = Vector{Float64}(undef, length(trange))
  for t in trange
    while true
      h1 = h+d*nrr*igd
      x2 = (7*u*h1)/(k*t)
      x4 = 2*j2
      q2 = (x4+1)/x4
      m = abs(7*(q2*coth(q2*x2)-(1/x4)*coth(x2/x4)))
      if isapprox(m, igd, atol = 10^(-10))
        break
      else
        igd = m
      end
    end  
    m_f[t] = m
  end
  plot(trange, m_f)
end
```

##### Plot:

[image: Plot as expected]

##### Changes for correctness:

- Changed `na = 6.0*10^(23)` to `na = 6.0e23`.
  Since `^` has a higher precedence than `*`, `10^23` is evaluated first, and since the operands are `Int` values, the result is also an `Int`. However, `Int` (i.e. `Int64`) can only hold numbers up to approximately `9 * 10^18`, so `10^23` overflows and gives a wrong result.

```
julia> 10^18
1000000000000000000

julia> 10^19 #overflow starts here
-8446744073709551616

julia> 10^23 #and gives a wrong value here too
200376420520689664
```

`6.0e23` avoids this problem by directly using the scientific [e-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation) to create a literal `Float64` value (`Float64` can hold this value without overflowing).

- Removed the `rad2deg` calls when calling `coth`. Julia trigonometric functions by default take radians, so there's no need to make this conversion.

##### Other changes

- Marked all the constants as `const`, and moved the rest of the code into a function. See [Performance tip: Avoid non-constant global variables](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#Avoid-global-variables)
- Changed the `abs(m - igd) < 10^-10` to `isapprox(m, igd, atol = 10^-10)` which performs basically the same check, but is clearer and more flexible (for eg. if you wanted to change to a relative tolerance `rtol` later).
- Stored the `1:400` as a named variable `trange`. This is just because it's used multiple times, so it's easier to manage as a variable.
- Changed `m_f = Float64[]` to `m_f = Vector{Float64}(undef, length(trange))` (and the `push!` at the end to an assignment). If the size of the array is known beforehand (as it is in this case), it's better for performance to pre-allocate it with `undef` values and then assign to it.
- Changed `u` and `k` also to use the scientific e-notation, for consistency and clarity (thanks to @DNF for suggesting the use of this notation in the comments).

Comment: I suggest changing `6.0*10^(23)` to `6.0e23`, `9.27*10.0^(-21)` to `9.27e-21`, etc., since the latter is the standard scientific float syntax, and is handled at parse time.